# Set default meta properties on Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have searched the documentation [here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-construction-options), and whilst there is a `meta` property on the `VueRouter` object, it doesn't seem to be doing anything (there is no description on the actual property in the docuementation)...

Consider the following routes:

```
let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: require('./views/Home').default
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        component: require('./views/About').default,
        meta: {
            transitionColor: '#000' // Note this property
        }
    }
];
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes,
    meta: {
        transitionColor: '#fff'
    }
});
```

The intention of the above code is to set the default `$route.meta.transitionColor` to `#fff` for all routes, and then allow the route to override this if it is supplied in the route level meta.

Is there a way to set default `meta` properties on Vue Router in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, it does not exist. However, with [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html), you can achieve something very similar.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   // manipulate route (e.g. set meta)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-). I wanted to avoid navigation guards for this purpose but it seems I don't have a choice

Comment: @BenCarey I thought so :) But maybe there is another solution without routes with which you can achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

NavGuards are pretty handy - here's an simple example how to achieve something like you requested but using another meta-property - here called in `router/index.ts` somewhere after `createRouter` was invoked. The example declares every page without an explicitly auth-declaration as private using the custom meta-property `requiresAuth` (and sets the page title afterwards, while we're on it):

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(to?.meta, "requiresAuth")) {
    to.meta.requiresAuth = true;
  }
  document.title =
    "APP BRAND - " + i18n.global.t(`component.appNav.${String(to.name)}`);
  next();
});
```